# How continuously bind child node to a parent node

Tags: asp.net

i have n number of employee names in a list let it be

> 1 2 3 . . n

I want to bind this details to my treeview1 like

> 1
>   -2
>   --3 . .
>   ---...n

How to do this.Can any one paste code for this
Thanks in Advance
Amrutha

Answer (score 0):

The node class should contain a reference to the parent node i.e:

```
public class Node {

   public Node parent;

   public Node(Node NewParent){
       this.parent=NewParent;
   }    
}
```

All node except the root should have a node as a parent, for the root the parent node must be set to null.